# Dynamically load images and keep aspect ratio

Tags: php, html, css

I have a picture gallery were I'm dynamically adding the pictures with PHP. Some of the images are horizontal and some are vertical. How do I set the width/height of the images and keep the aspect ratio without knowing if the image is horizontal or vertical? Right now the images are appearing square. Ideally I would like the client to change the images without having to adjust the code.

```
<?php
$filelist = glob("*.JPG");
foreach ($filelist as $file) {
    echo '<div class="gallerycell">';
    echo '<a href="'.$file.'"><img src="'.$file.'" width="300" height="300"></a>';
    echo '<p>'.substr($file,strpos($file,'/') + 0,-4).'</p>';
    echo '</div>';
}
?>

.gallerycell {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 30px;
}
```

Comment: @VXp That worked. If you add it as a post I'll mark it correct. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make *images* fully *responsive*, without changing their aspect ratio, add these rules to the `img` *element*:

```
img {
  display: block; /* removes bottom margin/whitespace */
  width: 100%; /* also scales with 100vw */
  max-height: 100vh; /* doesn't scale with 100% */
}
```